# PyMongo - How to query the number of properties in the object

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I need to retrieve numerical data from hundreds of documents looking like this one:

```
{
  "_id": "123",
  "Notes": {
    "1222": "Something is here"
  },
  "BehavioralData": {
    "Folder1": {
      "Sex": "Male",
      "Age": "22",
      "Date": "",
      "ResearchGroup": "",
      "Institution": "University of Manitoba"
    },
    "MoCA": {
      "Visual-Executive": "",
      "Naming": "NameHere",
      "Attention": "",
      "Language": "",
      "Abstraction": "",
      "Delayed Recall": "",
      "Orientation": "",
      "Education": "",
      "Total": ""
    }
  }
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
{
  "NotesLength": 1,
  "BehavioralLength": 2
}
```

Could you please suggest what tools I should use and how to get the result above? I am pretty sure that I should use aggregation for this problem, but I don't know what commands would help.

UPDATE: I am writing a script in Python using the PyMongo library. Apparently, PyMongo has some problems with the `$objectToArray` part. I get the following error:

> PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: The argument to
> $size must be an array, but was of type: null, full error: {'ok': 0.0,
> 'errmsg': 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: The
> argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null', 'code':
> 17124, 'codeName': 'Location17124', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime':
> Timestamp(1658726074, 53), 'signature': {'hash': b'L$\xb3\xcc
> \xdb\xb0#f}\xbaZ\xc6\rB\xf5\xe6]\x00\xc3', 'keyId':
> 7064465060042637317}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1658726074, 53)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With aggregation pipeline.

Since both `Notes` and `BehavioralData` are key-value pair, you need `$objectToArray` to convert the value to an array and next use `$size` to get the size of the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "NotesLength": {
        $size: {
          $objectToArray: "$Notes"
        }
      },
      "BehavioralLength": {
        $size: {
          $objectToArray: "$BehavioralData"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HmjYY0NNo-5)

Comment: By any chance, do you have any idea on how to use this pipeline in my python script? It returns errors when I implement your pipeline. Apparently, it has some problems with the "$objectToArray" part. It says"the argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null, full error"

Comment: May I know which MongoDB and PyMongo version used?

Comment: Anyway, any chance that `BehavioralData` and `Notes` objects are possibly null?

Comment: Pymongo 4.1.1 and MongoDB 6.0. And yes, it's possible that they are null. So far, to get the desired output, I use my python script. It basically extracts the entire collection and then measures the lengths of each object as a dictionary. It is a little slow, therefore, I am looking for more effective solutions.

Comment: I see, the object which is possibly null will lead the query to fail. You need to use `$ifNull` to check whether the object is null and assign an empty object if it is null. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rj9k0dbk5L_).