# How to get documents' objects length in MongoDB using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have hundreds of documents following the format below. Basically, each doc contains objects with the types "BehavioralData", "Notes", etc.

```json
    {
      "_id": "123",
      "Notes": {
        "1222": "Something is here"
      },
      "BehavioralData": {
        "Folder1": {
          "Sex": "Male",
          "Age": "22",
          "Date": "",
          "ResearchGroup": "",
          "Institution": "University of Manitoba"
        },
        "MoCA": {
          "Visual-Executive": "",
          "Naming": "NameHere",
          "Attention": "",
          "Language": "",
          "Abstraction": "",
          "Delayed Recall": "",
          "Orientation": "",
          "Education": "",
          "Total": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to query the collection using PyMongo in Python to get the following result:

```json
    {
      "NotesLength": 1,
      "BehavioralLength": 2
    }
```

What I did before, is upload documents one by one to my python script, and then measured the lengths of the dictionaries inside the dictionary. This takes a bit long as my python program queries the whole collection. Is there a way to do it faster than I do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: how to count number of keys in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980145/mongodb-how-to-count-number-of-keys-in-a-document)

Comment: What is different from your other question that asks the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103898/how-to-query-documents-objects-length-in-mongodb-using-pymongo